# Problems Notifications Firebase IOS

Tags: swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've followed Apple's suggestions to implement push notifications with Firebase, but I can't get notifications. I have created the APNS key in firebase and I have activated the notifications in the app. In Siginig & Capabilities I have added "Push Notification" "Background Modules" activating Remote notifiactions. This is the code in AppDelegate:

import UIKit import FirebaseCore import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool{

//Firebase

FirebaseApp.configure()
        

    // Push Notifications

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self



let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert,
     .badge, .sound]


UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    .requestAuthorization(
    options: authOptions,
    completionHandler: {_, _ in})



application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic:"topic_general")



return true
```

}
}

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
  
    // Push Notifications Mostrar aunque el movil este activo / Segundo Plano
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandle: @escaping
    (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void){
        
    completionHandle([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
    
}
```

Problems Notifications Firebase IOS

Comment: How are you testing it ? Are you sending a push from the firebase console ?

Comment: Hi Frank! Yes ! I have tried from the Firebase console and from the MacinCLoud emulator

Answer (score 0):

I just looked through what you did and a working version of Firebase Notifications I have running. I would try to share where there are differences

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseCore
```

Then

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (status, pushError) in
                if !status {
                    print(pushError?.localizedDescription as Any)
                }
            }
    } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    return true

}
```

after which

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let pushedInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    print(pushedInfo, "JSON Content of the Push Notification")
}
```

My ideas as to why you might not be getting the notifications:

- Push notifications can only be tested on a physical device. Doesn't work on simulator
- It is possible that push notifications is not authorised on the device.

Kindly check these ideas and the code differences. It is highly possible that the issue is somewhere there.

PS: I don't remember why I checked for `#available(iOS 10.0, *)` the code is a bit old.